# Get list of cells that contain a "text" within them using formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of users and what Groups they need to be added to. There are 18 different groups, but 100+ users. They don't all go into the same groups. I need to create a list of what users are going into what groups.

**Example:**

**Groups:**

VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON

**User List**

| User Name | User Groups |
| --- | --- |
| Michael Cardiff | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON |
| Brian Berger | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON |
| Adam Phipps | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON |
| Stuart Thomas | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON |
| Kerman Lafleur | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON |
| Ira Perry | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON |
| Pamela Trahan | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON |
| Carol Northam | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON |
| Sheena Ronsonet | VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_PROD_CLINICAL, VCO_PROD_EDM, VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON, VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN, VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL, VCO_STAGING_EDM, VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON |

On another sheet I then have the list of the Groups and want to use a formula to get the list of users that will be in that group. So the result should be something like:

| Group Name | User List |
| --- | --- |
| VCO_PROD_ES_OCHSNERLSN | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_PROD_CLINICAL | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_PROD_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas |
| VCO_PROD_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_PROD_EDM | Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_PROD_SC_LAWSON | Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam |
| VCO_STAGING_ES_OCHSNERLSN | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_STAGING_CLINICAL | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_STAGING_EDM_ADMINISTRATOR_LAWSON | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas |
| VCO_STAGING_HR_ADMINS_LAWSON | Michael Cardiff, Brian Berger, Adam Phipps, Stuart Thomas, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_STAGING_EDM | Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam, Sheena Ronsonet |
| VCO_STAGING_SC_LAWSON | Kerman Lafleur, Ira Perry, Pamela Trahan, Carol Northam |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=MAP(D2:D13,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($A$2:$A$10,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x,$B$2:$B$10))))))
```

---

Make sure to change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Alternatively, you use the following as well, if you are not using MS365.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($A$2:$A$10,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,$B$2:$B$10))))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down while the first approach doesn't as it will spill for the whole range.

---